# Twig variable for the "Member for" field of users

Tags: drupal, twig

I'm looking for the twig variable for the "member for" field in Drupal 8. Usually, I find the variables with `{{ content.field_THE_FIELD }}`, but impossible in this case.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `{{ dump(content|keys) }}`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found thanks to dump :)

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if u use {{ dump(content|keys) }} in your template, you will be able to see each variables.

Thanks Darkbee !